# Code for interest calculation in R for systematic investments

Tags: r

Suppose I deposit 1000 (P) dollars in bank every month for 60 (n) months and bank pays me 1 (rate) percent per month as interest.  Hence I can calculate the interest on each deposit as:

```
P=1000
n=60
rate=1

P*(rate/100)*(n:1)
[1] 600 590 580 570 560 550 540 530 520 510 500 490 480 470 460 450 440 430 420 410 400 390 380 370 360 350 340 330 320 310 300
[32] 290 280 270 260 250 240 230 220 210 200 190 180 170 160 150 140 130 120 110 100  90  80  70  60  50  40  30  20  10
```

and total interest (totalInt) as

```
totalInt = sum(P*(rate/100)*(n:1))
totalInt
[1] 18300
```

How can I calculate 'rate' if I know P, n and totalInt?  I tried following formula but it produces a series of values which do not make sense:

```
rate = totalInt * 100 / (P*(n:1))
> rate
 [1]   30.50000   31.01695   31.55172   32.10526   32.67857   33.27273   33.88889   34.52830   35.19231   35.88235   36.60000
[12]   37.34694   38.12500   38.93617   39.78261   40.66667   41.59091   42.55814   43.57143   44.63415   45.75000   46.92308
[23]   48.15789   49.45946   50.83333   52.28571   53.82353   55.45455   57.18750   59.03226   61.00000   63.10345   65.35714
[34]   67.77778   70.38462   73.20000   76.25000   79.56522   83.18182   87.14286   91.50000   96.31579  101.66667  107.64706
[45]  114.37500  122.00000  130.71429  140.76923  152.50000  166.36364  183.00000  203.33333  228.75000  261.42857  305.00000
[56]  366.00000  457.50000  610.00000  915.00000 1830.00000
> 


mean(rate)
[1] 142.736
```

The mean value is also too high and does not make sense.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a basic financial calculation.

Comment: I am trying to find code for taking into account a series or sequence of values in R. I think it is very much a programming problem.

Comment: The code is not your problem. Your interest calculation assumes no compounding, which is very unlikely. See [Wikipedia's entry on the time value of money](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_value_of_money). The [internal rate of return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_rate_of_return) often cannot be computed analytically.

Comment: You can either find a closed-form solution for your `totaInt` (there is one), or in the more general case, use a root finder.

Comment: The question is about solving a financial problem involving a series or sequence using R programming. This is also apparent from the accepted answer that elegantly shows the use of 'uniroot' function. It will be helpful to many learning R programming language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be new to R, so here are a couple of ways to do this.

If this was another programming language, you'd calculate compound interest this way:

```
# approach using loops - very inefficient in R
totalInt  <- 0
prin      <- P
for (i in 1:n) {
  totalInt  <- totalInt + prin*rate/100
  prin <- prin * (1+rate/100)
}
totalInt
# [1] 816.6967
```

Since R is a vectorized language, this is the preferred way in R.

```
# vectorized approach - very efficient in R
prin <- P * (1+rate/100)^(0:(n-1))
int  <- prin * rate/100
totalInt <- sum(int)
totalInt
# [1] 816.6967
```

This code creates a vector, `prin` with the principle at the beginning of each period, and then a vector `int` containing the interest earned in that period. The approach below is a more compact version of the same thing.

```
# vectorized approach simplified
P * sum((1+rate/100)^(0:(n-1))*rate/100)
# [1] 816.6967
```

So to do the reverse, e.g. calculate the rate given P, n, and totalInt, we use the `uniroot(...)` function applied to the function `f(...)`, below. Read the documentation on `uniroot(...)`.

```
f <- function(rate,P,n,totalInt) {
  totalInt - P * sum((1+rate/100)^(0:(n-1))*rate/100)
}

result <- uniroot(f,P=1000,n=60,totalInt=816.7, lower=0, upper=100)$root
result
# [1] 1.000003
```

Comment: The uniroot funciton is new to me and very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, let's add a variable: `fracRate = rate/100`

Since `totalInt = sum(P*fracRate*(n:1))` then `totalInt = P*fracRate*(n+1)*n/2`.

Now we can rearrange to get `fracRate = 2*totalInt /(P*(n+1)*n)`. You can calculate percent rate with `rate = 100*fracRate`.

---

The calculation isn't really R specific, so perhaps you should try asking on [Math@SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), where answers can also include the nicer LaTeX equation formatting.

Your method for calculating assumes that the bank calculates interest from principal only. In reality, interest is usually compounded.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks. I accepted other answer since it gives how to do it using R programming.