# How to plot an investment of 1$ in each of two plots

Tags: r, plot

suppose you invest 1$ in the end of December 1933 in each asset and hold it until end of December 2019. Make a plot which shows how your initial investment of 1$ evolves over time.

```
  #plotting log of treasury bills
TBS2_dates <- TBS2[,1]
log_ret_treasury <- cbind(TBS2_dates, ret_treasury[,4])
plot(log_ret_treasury,  type="l",
     xlab = "monthly obs", ylab = "Rate of return in decimals, ex. (0.01 = 1%", 
     main = "monthly rate of return on the US Treasury Bills 3months 1934-2019")

#plotting log index
IND_dates <- IND[,3]
log_ret_index <- cbind(IND_dates, ret_index[,1])
plot(log_ret_index, type="l",
     xlab = "monthly obs", ylab = "Rate of return in decimals, ex. (0.01 = 1%",
     main = "monthly rate of return on US stock index 1934-2020")
```

how do i make a plot of my 1$ investment in both of these plots? Thanks for any help ^^

```
> dput(head(log_ret_index))
structure(list(date = structure(c(-13119, -13091, -13060, -13030, 
-12999, -12969), class = "Date"), `ret_index[, 1]` = c(0.119363119998702, 
-0.0245867931894417, 0.00441523847340962, -0.0185153561852664, 
-0.0750177705101481, 0.0250281660421121)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that your question is not about plotting, it's about homework that is asking you to calculate compound interest and then demonstrate that in a plot. You need to know how to do compound interest. What have you tried? Is there sample data we can use?

Comment: I have already plotted the two df´s in two plots. Im new to R, so i am unsure how to give you the sample data. But how would you proceed if you were supposed to plot your investment over time compared to the plots?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Thommas! You've provided sample code which is good, but we have nothing to use that code on. Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`). Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Thank you :) i posted the us stock index head for you to see :)

Comment: Thanks for posting the `dput` output. So you're interested in how to plot a line, and your `plot` command actually does that, so ... I think we're back to this: you need to know how to do compound interest, initially this question has nothing to do with "how to plot". It should instead be "how to calculate", and then plotting should work itself out.

Comment: Further: plotting the schedule of rates is interesting, but you need to derive your own `data.frame` based on this schedule of return rates. If you know how to calculate compounding interest but don't know how to do it in R, then please explain what you understand.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24595890/3358272

Comment: Yes. as i said earlier, im a newbie on this subject.. But if that is what i need to do to get my wish true, how can i do this in each of my df's? i suppose the method is identical for both?

Comment: You said you are new to R, but it sounds like you don't know how to do compound interest in general, is that right? For instance, if you were to do this somewhere else (e.g., Excel), do you know how you would do it?

Comment: i find excel way easier than R, the thing is that we are obligated to do all calculations in R. i saw your link with the example. I see the OP had frequent investments every month. In my case it is just one investment at the start of 1933 to 2019. I imagine i can apply a formula containing the dataframes i made my plot from with the 1$ investment. Or is my logic wrong? thanks ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is contiguous month-wise, then cumulative interest can be calculated with `cumprod`, or `cum`ulative `prod`uct. Since it's interest, we need to add 1 first.

**Edit**: this is monthly compounding on an annual return rate, I think, so I'll divide the rate by 12 ...

```r
cumprod(1 + log_ret_index[,2]/12)
# [1] 1.009947 1.007878 1.008248 1.006693 1.000399 1.002486
```

Since you want to go from 1933 to 2019, for the sake of execution I'll carry the last rate (0.025) forward ten years:

```r
out <- cumprod(1 + c(log_ret_index[,2], rep(log_ret_index[6,2], 120)) / 12)
head(out)
# [1] 1.009947 1.007878 1.008248 1.006693 1.000399 1.002486
tail(out)
# [1] 1.273904 1.276561 1.279224 1.281892 1.284565 1.287245
```

Let's flash forward some decades:

```r
tail(cumprod(1 + c(log_ret_index[,2], rep(log_ret_index[6,2], 10*12)) / 12))
# [1] 1.273904 1.276561 1.279224 1.281892 1.284565 1.287245
tail(cumprod(1 + c(log_ret_index[,2], rep(log_ret_index[6,2], 20*12)) / 12))
# [1] 1.635760 1.639171 1.642590 1.646016 1.649449 1.652889
tail(cumprod(1 + c(log_ret_index[,2], rep(log_ret_index[6,2], 30*12)) / 12))
# [1] 2.100401 2.104782 2.109172 2.113571 2.117979 2.122397
tail(cumprod(1 + c(log_ret_index[,2], rep(log_ret_index[6,2], 40*12)) / 12))
# [1] 2.697025 2.702651 2.708287 2.713936 2.719596 2.725269
tail(cumprod(1 + c(log_ret_index[,2], rep(log_ret_index[6,2], 50*12)) / 12))
# [1] 3.463122 3.470345 3.477583 3.484836 3.492104 3.499388
tail(cumprod(1 + c(log_ret_index[,2], rep(log_ret_index[6,2], 60*12)) / 12))
# [1] 4.446830 4.456105 4.465399 4.474712 4.484045 4.493397
tail(cumprod(1 + c(log_ret_index[,2], rep(log_ret_index[6,2], 70*12)) / 12))
# [1] 5.709963 5.721872 5.733806 5.745765 5.757749 5.769757
tail(cumprod(1 + c(log_ret_index[,2], rep(log_ret_index[6,2], 80*12)) / 12))
# [1] 7.331891 7.347183 7.362507 7.377863 7.393251 7.408671
```

(Yes, there are much better ways to calculate and show that ...)

To me, this suggests that **if** you had invested a single `$1` contribute in 1933; **and** the rate stayed at its last `2.5%` annual return; **and** you let it sit for 80 years; **then* you might have multiplied your dollar by over 7x over those eight decades.

Comment: when i did your calculation on the big scale i got 41964.87 but the head is 0.119363 and tail is 0.0280508. how can it be this big when the values are that small?

Comment: See my edit ... the `/12` is most likely a fix here, otherwise `$1 --> $20B` ... unlikely :-)

Comment: thanks. That helps ^^But if you see my screenshot i added on the post. I don't understand how it can grow 7x in those years according to the plot.

Comment: Your screenshot shows you still using `cumprod(1 + log_ret_index[,2])` instead of `cumprod(1 + log_ret_index[,2]/12)`, not sure if that's in error. But ... verify with https://www.investor.gov/financial-tools-calculators/calculators/compound-interest-calculator, values: initial `1`, monthly contrib `0`, length in years `80`, est interest `2`, int variance `0`, compound `monthly`, and hit calculate, and it returns `$4.95`. In R, run `tail(cumprod(rep(1 + 0.02/12, 80*12)))`, and the last value is 4.946440. I'm not saying I'm a business expert, but the math seems to line up.

Comment: alright. ill try that out. and hopefully everything works out! thanks R2evans :))

Comment: i checked ther gov website. i should have 5.58$ after 86 years. in R, the last number in cumprod(1 + log_ret_index[,2]/12) gives me the same number in thousands. Something is wrong. The thing is that im also supposed to plot how the investment involves over time... Maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: never mind. brainfart on my part! now how do i plot this

Comment: `plot(log_ret_index[,1], out)`? It's not appropriate to put it on the same y-axis since it's a different "unit" than the "rate".

Comment: thankyou so much sir:) quick question: how do you know the rate is 2% im just curious since according to the plot of rate of return on the us. stock index shows a lower number on the tail compared to the head. Should not this in theory give me a negative end value?

Comment: 2% was merely an example, since I don't have all of your data, and I thought it would be an easy verification of the concept.